# defer func not recover

Tags: go, recover, panic, defer-keyword

So, I've been fiddling around with go, and I found that function below recover successfully

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func a() {  
    defer func(){
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            fmt.Println("Recovered", r)
        }
    }()
    n := []int{5, 7, 4}
    fmt.Println(n[3])
    fmt.Println("normally returned from a")
}

func main() {  
    a()
    fmt.Println("normally returned from main")
}
```

But this is not

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func r() {  
    if r := recover(); r != nil {
        fmt.Println("Recovered", r)
    }
}

func a() {  
    defer func(){
        r()
    }()
    n := []int{5, 7, 4}
    fmt.Println(n[3])
    fmt.Println("normally returned from a")
}

func main() {  
    a()
    fmt.Println("normally returned from main")
}
```

Can anybody explain why? I've been looking for answer but did not found anything that i can fully understand.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A call to recover will only stop a panic when called directly from the deferred function. Here's the relevant text from the [recover documentation](https://godoc.org/builtin#recover):

> Executing a call to recover inside a deferred function (but not any function called by it) stops the panicking sequence by restoring normal execution and retrieves the error value passed to the call of panic.

Comment: I still don't get it, the first example works and if I use `defer r()` it works too. but not when it's like second example, so I can only use `recover()` behind one function call? like `g()` -> `r()` but not `g()` -> `f()` -> `r()` ?

Comment: Recover restores normal execution when called directly a deferred function, but not any function called by the deferred function. The call tree of  g() -> f() -> recover() will not restore normal execution when  g() returns.

Comment: It should be noted that `a()` could call an external function which panics - and panics in some other many-levels-deep nested function call - and `a()` can still recover the panic, since it initiated the call chain.

Comment: this one helped me a lot to understand defer, panic and recover logic. 
https://go.dev/blog/defer-panic-and-recover