# Why golang can not recover from a panic in a function called by the defer function

Tags: go, recover, panic, defer-keyword

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func myRecover() {
    if r := recover(); r != nil {
        fmt.Println(r)
    }
}

func main() {
    defer func() {
        myRecover()
    }()
    panic("The gas price is skyrocketing!")
}
```

The code above can not recover from the panic somehow the code below can.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            fmt.Println(r)
        }
    }()
    panic("The gas price is skyrocketing!")
}
```

It is so confusing. I want to know why.

Comment: perhaps call panic from the deferred function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58443138/defer-func-not-recover

Comment: I know the doc says we need to call recover() directly from the deferred function. I want to know why this happens? How panic is propagated so that a function called by a deferred function can not perceive a panic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [specification says](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Handling_panics):

> The return value of recover is nil if any of the following conditions holds:
>
> - ...
> - recover was not called directly by a deferred function.

In the first example, `recover` is not called directly by the deferred function.  The `recover` function always returns `nil` in this case.

You can use `myRecover` by deferring the function directly.

```
func main() {
    defer myRecover()
    panic("The gas price is skyrocketing!")
}
```

Comment: It's odd in this case that the first code example will compile at all. Surely if a `recover()` call outside of any `defer` block is always `nil`, there is no reason to allow that code to exist, and the compiler could refuse to compile it?

Comment: Ah, never mind. It's so that `func foo() { x := recover() }; ... defer foo()` works as intended. The problem OP is having is that `defer func() { foo() }` doesn't work, but if they'd just typed `defer foo()` this would work fine.